# yii2 composer update error: Invalid version string "2.*"

Tags: composer-php, yii2

I'm use composer update in a `Yii2` project, but it is exiting with an exception.
I have updated composer to the lastest version, `c6cc6dd6070871f4b198ed39f76dd8047c116b02`, but it still doesn't work:

```
Importing tag v2.0.2 (2.0.2.0)
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/yii2-pjax (v2.0.1)
Reading /home/xiaoai/.composer/cache/repo/github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax/bower-f07ce95f6098c0bd5421789a20789f39a19be73b from cache
Importing tag v2.0.1 (2.0.1.0)
Reading /home/xiaoai/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-yiisoft$yii2-bootstrap.json from cache
Reading /home/xiaoai/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-bower-asset$bootstrap.json from cache
Downloading https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap
Writing /home/xiaoai/.composer/cache/repo/https---bower.herokuapp.com-packages/bootstrap-3c71cc99d2fc1c12a3d3e1b27e448ca612a89a1d-package.json into cache
Adding VCS repository bower-asset/bootstrap
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/contents/bower.json?ref=master
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/commits/master
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/tags?per_page=100
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/git/refs/heads?per_page=100



  [UnexpectedValueException]                                              
  Could not parse version constraint <=2.*: Invalid version string "2.*"  

Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:461
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser->parseConstraint() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:257
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser->parseConstraints() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:234
 Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader->parseLinks() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:123
 Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader->load() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:174
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->preInitBranchPackage() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:138
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->initBranches() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:45
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->initialize() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:178
 Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:104
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:60
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepositoryInstance() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:39
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepository() at /home/xiaoai/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AbstractAssetsRepository.php:139
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:199
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:188
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:161
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromPackage() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:273
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromJobs() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:324
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:177
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:505
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:230
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:140
```

I don't think this is my mistake, but how do I fix the exception?

Comment: To fix this exception you need to provide more details on your project. But `<=2.*` makes no sense indeed.

Comment: Somewhat off topic but I still can't figure out why they decided to start relying on a plugin that was in early beta at the moment they released and that needs to be installed globally...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Michael Nguyen's answer did not work for me, but updating to dev-master did:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"
```

One may also need to update composer itself:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Also there was an extensive discussion on this yesterday: [link](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/pull/137).

UPDATE. It seems to me at this moment "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev" is better again.

Comment: i am glad the bug has been fixed. Composer update should work now. If not, you need to do composer global update so the fxp is updated to v1.0.3

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and discussed on Yii Forum. It seems like this is a bug with "fxp/composer-asset-plugin".

Try

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.1"
```

Then do whatever you need with composer

The bug is discussed at https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/issues/129

Comment: since there have been a fix to fxp (v1.0.3), so if you are do composer global update, it will updated fxp to latest 1.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

It helped for me

```
composer self-update
composer global update
```

Comment: this worked the best for me, I was running self-update and had no idea I had to also do a global update.  Thanks.