# Want to integrate TCPDF in YII2

Tags: php, yii2, tcpdf

I want to integrate `TCPDF` in Yii2 Framework. I tried to install it with composer but I get this error:

```
[UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint <=2.*: Invalid version string "2.*"
```

I downloaded the TCPDF code from [it's github repository](https://github.com/Requilence/yii2-tcpdf) and put it in the `vendor` folder, configured it in `web.php` but its not working: the class is not loading in the specific controller.

I want to generate a PDF for the detail page

Comment: Have You tried run `php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin: 1.0.1"`? It's common problem.

Comment: @Patryk Radziszewski, yes i tried with but got same error as i mensioned

Comment: Try with `php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin: 1.0.3"` and then `php composer.phar self-update`

Comment: @Glapa, same error :(

Comment: And to what value is set `minimum-stability` in composer.json file?

Comment: @Glapa, its "minimum-stability": "dev", "prefer-stable" : true,

Comment: Try `php composer.phar global update`. If it wont work i advise to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681630/yii2-composer-update-error-invalid-version-string-2) thread.

Comment: @Glapa, i have also tried that but its already up to date. but my issue is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86609/discussion-between-albert-akki-and-glapa).